# Populate data from file into class objects for each line then store it in a list

Tags: python, list, object

I would like to populate each line in a file into a seperate object of class student from another module then store it in a list but i'm receiving an error line 6 NameError: name 'Sid' is not defined. here is my code each line in txt file has values such as studentid,studentname,studentage

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, Sid, Sname, Sage):
        self.Sid =Sid
        self.Sname =Sname
        self.Sage =Sage

from student import Student

def readStudent():
    student_list = []
    with open("Student.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            line = Student(Sid, Sname, Sage)
            student_list.append(line).split(" ")
            print(student_list)
```

Comment: Where you have written `line = Student(Sid, Sname, Sage)`, what exactly do you expect that to mean? In particular, where do you expect the values for `Sid`, `Sname` and `Sage` to come from? Where you have `for line in f:`, what exactly do you expect `line` to look like each time through the loop? You should start by trying to explain every step of the intended process, in order, in plain English words. You may find it helps to take out a real pen and paper, write it by hand, and draw diagrams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vars names `Sid`, `Sname` and `Sage` dosen't exist in your foor loop, those vars have been defined in your class `Student`. If I understand, you have a text file with 3 columns and (each column represent `Sid`, `Sname` and `Sage` respectively).

```
def readStudent():
    student_list = []
    with open("Student.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            student = Student(*line.split())
            student_list.append(student)
```

Comment: When trying your code i received this error IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level in student_list.append(student)

Comment: `IndentationError` means that you have an extra tab maybe in your code!

Comment: The code works but i am not getting any result when returning the list it only works when using print function which provides weird output such as <student.Student object at 0x000002315EA422E0>

Comment: you have to use a `return` stament to return the `studen_list` list!. If you write a more explainable example i could help you better!

Comment: using the return statement when the for loop finishes when calling the function i get no output from the function sorry if i am not clear

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant something like this:

```
for line in f:
    sid, sname, sage = line.split(",")
    student = Student(sid, sname, int(sage))
    student_list.append(student)
```

Oh, and you forgot to `return student_list` from the function.

Btw if you learning python then don't forget to check out pep-8 style guide: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Sorry, i am new to python do i apply the return statement in the same indentation level as the for loop in which it will return the list after the loop is done am i correct? Also since values in txt file are separated by a comma for each value in a line  what does the .split method do? Thanks

Comment: Also, the return statement does not provide any result only the print function does